# pyautogui keyboard.add_hotkey works only to map hotkeys with single keys

Tags: python, hotkeys, pyautogui

I use Parallels on a MacBook and when I use:

```
keyboard.add_hotkey('f2', lambda: click_text_field())
```

it is all fine.
But when I combine keys, such as

```
keyboard.add_hotkey('alt+f2', lambda: click_text_field())
```

it won't work.

Any ideas why not? Any suggestions of workarounds?

many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

On Mojave, there's a new security feature where you must explicitly allow applications to use your mouse/keyboard. Have a look in Security Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy > Accessibility - you might have to allow Parallels.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
keyboard.add_hotkey('alt, f2', lambda: click_text_field())
```

Comment: also not working, keyboard.add_hotkey seems to work only with single keys on Mac. any ideas what else could I try? thanks